# web page on apache linux (centos 7) not apear in other computer of my lan

Tags: linux, apache, centos, webserver, centos7

I'm trying to conect to my web page since another computer of my lan through a browser, I put the ip address of my web server (apache linux on centos 7) but it can be able to conect. In my web server i put the following comands:

systemctl enable httpd.service
systemctl start httpd.service
nmap localhost -p 80

It give me all ok, but i can't conect of other computer on my lan.
I have only a switch.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling SELinux. On CentOS, edit the file /etc/selinux/config. Change the line that says

> SELINUX=permissive

to

> SELINUX=disabled

Save the file and reboot the server.

Also, stop the default firewall.

> sudo systemctl stop firewalld

And to disable it from starting on boot

> sudo systemctl disable firewalld